# JFrog Artifactory multi-level dependency

Tags: java, gradle, artifactory

I have a Java application which uses a custom library named `com.abc.XYZLogging`.

This library is dependent on `org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.7.RELEASE` and `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10`.

So the dependency diagram is like this:

```
com.abc.XYZLogging
|---org.springframework:spring-context:4.3.7.RELEASE
|---org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.10
     |---log4j:log4j:1.2.17
```

All the artifacts are present in the correct locations and in the same repo. However gradle picks up only the first level `com.abc.XYZLogging` and it does not pickup any other dependency in the hierarchy.

I use gradle 4.2 and Oracle JDK 1.8.144. This happens even when I invoke gradle clean build from command line and via Buildship plugin in eclipse.

Is there any dependency mapping missing in my artifactory ?

Comment: Could you post your gradle.build or whatever file you use to declare the dependency ? Also check if those dependencies are transitory.

Comment: Hi Victor, Thanks for the reply. I use gradle for building. I have the given the dependency correctly. With the same gradle file, the dependencies are picked up from nexus without any issues, but in artifactory only the topmost library is picked, others levels are not.

Comment: have you just change the file to point to artifactory? Sometimes it is better to use artifactory's gradle plugin

Comment: I will leave the plugin config here, should this be the issue.. If not we can discuss further.

Answer (score 0):

Example of how to configure a repository based on Artifactory to behave like in a Maven style using artifactory's own plugin, as sometimes just pointing to artifactory as usually done is not enough.

This is just an example for getting libs from artifactory, to publish extra config is necessary. Also this example is for a multi-build where the build script is separated from the artifactory config. More at: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Gradle+Artifactory+Plugin

This first example is getting the plugin from artifactory itself, and the second for jcenter.

```
buildscript {

    dependencies { classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release" }

    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username = artifactory_username
                password = artifactory_password
            }
            url "https://.../artifactory/libs-release"
        }
    }
}

allprojects{
    apply plugin: org.jfrog.gradle.plugin.artifactory.ArtifactoryPlugin
    artifactory {
        resolve {
            contextUrl = "https://.../artifactory"
            repoKey = 'libs-global'
            username = artifactory_username
            password = artifactory_password
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:latest.release"
  }
}
apply plugin: "com.jfrog.artifactory"
```

---

OR simpler, in newer versions

```
plugins {
  id "com.jfrog.artifactory" version "latest.release"
}
```

so you can use blocks like:

```
       artifactory {
            resolve {
                contextUrl = "https://.../artifactory"
                repoKey = 'libs-global'
                username = artifactory_username
                password = artifactory_password
            }
        }
```